# Correct pattern to wait for dispatch in a reusable component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Let's imagine the following components in a React/Redux application :

- **AllFiles** which lists all the files ever sent and is always displayed into a left panel
- **Folder** which contains a list of files and one **FileUpload** component to append files to this folder.
- **FileUpload** which can be used anywhere on the plaform and multiple times on the same page, and simple upload a new file

What is a correct pattern for **FileUpload** to :

- send a file using an async API (react-thunk)
- update the store to trigger **AllFiles** render
- warns "Folder" component that a new File is uploaded

A first guess would be to try `dispatch(uploadFile()).then(onFileUploaded)` into **FileUpload** component. **Folder** will be warned with an "onUploaded" callback passed to the **FileUpload** component. Then, update its internal state by adding the new uploaded file.

But dispatch and promises can't be combined.

**Option 1 :**

Both **Folder** and **FileUpload** components should not use the store to keep their data. But they should use their internal state to do so.

Then, "FileUpload" should not dispatch an action, but simple call an async action with a promise.

How to update the store for **AllFiles** in this situation ? In **FileUpload** component after the promise ?

**Option 2 :**

All components should be their state into the store.

Then, how to design the store to enable multiple instances of **FileUpload** in the same page ?

Comment: A thunk action can dispatch multiple actions: `const uploadFile = (args)=>(dispatch,getState)=>{dispatch(loading();upload(args).then(()=>dispatch(success()),dispatch(fail())) )}` Why would you want the logic of what needs to be dispatched after upload file in the component and instead just put it in the thunk action?

Comment: @HMR Because **FileUpload** can be launched from differents contexts. Here I need to add the uploaded file to the Folder. But elsewhere I could save an user profile icon for example.

Comment: Then the logic what to do should still be in the action and not in the component. The component can pass a value to the action creator/thunk action to indicate what to do next but should not be bothered by actually implementing it.

Comment: @HMR So every time I use the **FileUpload** in a different context, I have to update my thunk action to add a side effect ? It feels wrong, cause the onUpload thunk action will become a huge function with multiple purposes (update user icon, update folder files list, ...).